# Two classes contaoin members of each other

Tags: c++

I have two classes: User.h and Room.h and both of them contain a pointer to an object of the other class (user to room and room to user).
I think i understand how to include the **.h** files but i still get errors in one of my **.cpp** files (user.cpp).

**user.h**

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

class Room;

using namespace std;

class User
{
private:
    Room* _currRoom;
public:
    //some functions...
};

#endif
```

**room.h**

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

#include "User.h"

class Room
{
private:
    vector<User*> _users;
    User* _admin;
    int _maxUsers;
    int _questionTime;
    int _questionsNo;
    string _name;
    int _id;

public:
    Room(int id, User* admin, string name, int maxUsers, int questionsNo,int questionTime);
    //more functions...
};

#endif
```

I included user.h in room.cpp and room.h in user.cpp
What is the problem with what I did?

Comment: You shouldn't include `cpp` files

Comment: If you have errors you should share them.  We love error text.

Comment: Error 1 error C2514: 'Room' : class has no constructors, I called the constructor in user.cpp

Comment: And what line of code causes that error?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I haven't included .cpp files

Comment: _currRoom = new Room(roomId, this, roomName, maxUsers, questionsNo, questionTime); in user.cpp

Comment: your post says otherwise "Now in the .cpp files I included in Room.cpp, [...]"

Comment: @Rakete1111 sorry for the confusion, I just showed what .h I included in each of the .cpp files

Comment: OK... you should really make your question clearer and add all relevant info that you posted in the comments

Comment: [C++ - Forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `room.h`, replace `#include "User.h"` with a forward declaration instead.  Use forward declarations in the `.h` files, and move the corresponding `#include` statements to the `.cpp` files:

user.h

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

class Room;

using namespace std;

class User
{
private:
    Room* _currRoom;
public:
    //some functions...
};

#endif
```

user.cpp

```
#include "user.h"
#include "room.h"
...
```

room.h

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class User;

class Room
{
private:
    vector<User*> _users;
    User* _admin;
    int _maxUsers;
    int _questionTime;
    int _questionsNo;
    string _name;
    int _id;

public:
    Room(int id, User* admin, string name, int maxUsers, int questionsNo, int questionTime);
    //more functions...
};

#endif
```

room.cpp

```
#include "room.h"
#include "user.h"
...
```

If you don't do the forward declarations in this manner, you can end up in a circular situation where a header indirectly includes itself via another header (A includes B, which includes A) and thus its header guard has already been defined preventing its declarations from being processed, thus causing errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can continue